# trying to uninstall scrapy, cannot and get the message 'owned by OS'

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

Trying to uninstall Scrapy 0.24 from my Ubuntu system so I can do a clean install of the latest version 1.0.5. But when I go

```
sudo pip uninstall scrapy
```

I get the following message:

```
 Not uninstalling Scrapy at /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7, owned by OS
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/p/python-scrapy/uninstall/index.html   <-- try this

Comment: How did you install it?